# List yarn application jobs

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, amazon-emr

I'm working on AWS environment and I'm trying to get this application infos via CLI, but I didn't find any YARN command for that:

EMR Application Jobs:
[image]

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

To list all running application on the cluster you can use: `yarn application -list`

Other useful commands are:
`yarn application -status <application id>`
to get the status of your applications that you've submitted and to get logs for an application you can run

`yarn logs -applicationId <application id>`

Here's the documentation for other commands you can run from the master node https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/YarnCommands.html